# How do I reach these isolated graffiti spots in Versum Hill?

Tags: bomb-rush-cyberfunk

In Versum Hill there's an underground area with several graffiti spots seemingly isolated from the rest of the map. There's a long hallway leading to it that I can't find any way to reach.

How do I reach these seemingly isolated graffiti spots?

[image: Map of Versum Hill with graffiti spots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grind the train tracks into the tunnel will lead you to that garage.